# TeamViewer C# starting remote control

Tags: c#, connection, teamviewer

Hello I want to create a TeamViewer session via user Id and password. Each computer is in my database and I want to use starting connection with web browser like this:

```
teamviewer8://remotecontrol/?connectcc=000000000
```

How I can put pre-set password to this link?

Thanks for all help

Comment: syntax for clarity in understanding the question

Comment: https://integrate.teamviewer.com/en/develop/api/documentation/

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson TeamViewer remote control can be open by web browser and in my code I want to start teamviewer remotecontrol triggered by web browser. All members teamviewer have pre-set password for ex. "111111" and while starting up connection like that I want to set it to web browser link by value. The "000 000 000" part of code that I wrote is teamviewer ID of far pc. Is there anyway to start up connection w/o messing up with api ?

Comment: @TuRQuaS3 did you have any update in the matter?

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer unfortunately.

Comment: @OmegaExtern API Documentation moved to https://www.teamviewer.com/en/for-developers/#api-documentation-section